# Azure subscription reactivation

Tags: azure

I'm trying to create a resource group to use azure machine learning studio but my subscription has been deactivated and trying to activate has not been a success since the reactivation button has been greyed out.

Comment: Hello Andy, did you create this account under Free Subscription or is it paid?

Answer (score 1):

@Andy Kwesi There are many factors for a subscription to get disabled. A few are listed in this URL - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cost-management-billing/manage/subscription-disabled you can follow the instructions from the link to re-activate your disabled subscription. If you fail to do so, a better avenue would be to reach out to Azure subscription management team by raising a support request. Here is the link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request or https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/getsupport?wf=0&tenant=ClassicCommercial&oaspworkflow=start_1.0.0.0&locale=en-us&supportregion=en-us&pesid=15470&ccsid=636233463407635340 to create support case.

Let me know if there are any challenges creating a support request.

Note: Azure billing and subscription management support is provided free of cost.

Comment: Thanks very much. I did send sent a request and my issue has been resolved.